# Html text starts with < and end with > displays blank

Tags: html

MY HTML is

```
<div> <Sample text> </div>
<div> <SampleText> </div>
```

In above two cases "blank content" is displaying after DOM creation.

I am expecting to display text as it is.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: You need to use `&lt;` and `&gt;`, These are called __HTML Entities__, like `<div> &lt;Sample text&gt; </div>`

Comment: You need to use HTML Entities to display HTML markup with HTML characters, especially if it's XHTML.

Comment: This is HTML 101, nothing to do with JavaScript or jQuery - unless you are trying to set the content from JS based on user-entered data or something like that?

Comment: Great sir @Satpal

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `&lt;` and `&gt;`, These are called [HTML Entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)

```html
<div> &lt;Sample text&gt; </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some characters are reserved in HTML.

If you use the less than (<) or greater than (>) signs in your text, the browser might mix them with tags.

Character entities are used to display reserved characters in HTML.

To display a less than sign (<) we must write: `&lt; or &#60;`

Like in your case,

```
<div> &lt;Sample text&gt; </div>
```

as mentioned by others

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div>  &lt;Sample text &gt; </div>
<div> &lt;SampleText </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
<div> &lt;Sample text&gt; </div>
<div> &lt;Sample text&gt; </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div> &lt;Sample text> </div>
<div> &lt;SampleText > </div>
```